# C++ , winapi Compare two WCHAR * strings

Tags: c++, string, winapi, wchar

I want to compare two `WCHAR*` strings.

How to do it?

P.S.
I would like to **ignore case** while comparing.

I know you can use `strcmpi` but it id not working for `WCHAR*`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For case sensitive comparison, look at [`wcscmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

For case insensitive comparison, look at [`_wcsicmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: How to use it so that I can ignore case?

Comment: @SoumyajitRoy I'm sure something exists, but this question was tagged `winapi`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `WCHAR_t` versions of `strcmp`. You can find the definitions [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wcscmp).

For case insensitive comparison use [wcscasecmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wcscasecmp).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using StrCmpLogicalW()? Depending on your need that might be preferable to wcscmp.

Comment: Again, this is case sensitive.

Comment: No, it's not, take a look at the MSDN page. :-)

Comment: However, `StrCmpLogicalW` would care for prefix numbers in string.

Answer (score 0):

There is `lstrcmpi` function in Win32 API which works with `LPCTSTR` instead of `const char *`. Don't know why it is not popular - I use it since 1994 (mostly `lstrcmp` without "i").